# MYSQL - calculate percentage of book copies of book titled ‘The Alchemist’ are currently on loan

Tags: mysql, percentage

the relational schema of database libarary is:

```
BOOK (ISBN_no, author, title, edition, year_published, no_of_pages)
BOOK_COPY (book_id, ISBN_no, status, load_period_weeks)

insertion
BOOK (‘0062502174’, ‘Paulo Coelho’, ‘The Alchemist’, 1, 1993, 267)

BOOK_COPY (‘BC201’, ‘0062502174’, ‘On Loan’, 4)
BOOK_COPY (‘BC202’, ‘0062502174’, ‘In’, 2)
BOOK_COPY (‘BC203’, ‘0062502174’, ‘In’, 4)
```

now, I have to calculate the percentage book copies of book titled ‘The Alchemist’ are currently on loan.
here is what i have tried. but i did not get the correct result.

```
Select book.title,  concat(round(((count(book.title) / count(book_copy.ISBN_no)) * 100 ),2), '%') as Result
from book join book_copy
on book.ISBN_no = book_copy.ISBN_no
where book.title = 'The Alchemist';
```

Comment: What is the result you are expecting so that we can compare?

Comment: percentage should come 33.33%

Comment: Your query does not consider the status of the copies in any way, therefore definitely cannot provide the right answer! You should use conditional counting.

Comment: for the book having title -The Alchemist

Comment: title | percentage of book copies

Comment: title                  | percentage of book copies
The Alchemist | 33.33%

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional counting. In this case the query uses `CASE` to count only non-null expressions. For example:

```
select
  max(book.title) as title,
  count(case when status = 'On Loan' then 1 end) / count(*) as result
from book 
join book_copy on book.ISBN_no = book_copy.ISBN_no
where book.title = 'The Alchemist'
group by book.ISBN_no
```

Comment: not working - it gives error - Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'when status = 'On Loan' then 1 end) / count(*) as result from book  join book_co' at line 3

Comment: @ShubhamJyoti Try now.